# safari browser download csv not working using Blob

Tags: csv

### chrome and mozilla browser working properly but in mac safari browser not working

```
  var convertedCsv = "name,Designation,City,State,email,mobileNumber,roleType,signUpDate+\n" +
                    "A,B,C,D,F,G,I,J \n" +
                    "A1,B1,C1,D1,F1,G1,I1,J1";
            var data = new Blob([convertedCsv], {type: 'text/csv'});
            var csvFile = window.URL.createObjectURL(data);
            window.open(csvFile, "amit");
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a Node Proxy and set headers as:

```
router.get("/downloadList/:Id/:fileName", function(req, res) {
// Set hedders to CSV and giving file name
res.setHeader('Content-disposition', 'attachment; filename=' + req.params.fileName + '.csv');
res.set('Content-Type', 'text/csv');
var url = 'https://' + host_name + '/v1/downloadCsv/' + req.params.Id;
client.get(url, function(data) {
    dateReceived(data);
});

function dateReceived(data) {
    var outerData = data;
        res.send(outerData);
    }
});
```

From client side, request pointing to node JS route:

```
function downloadCSV(Id) {
     // Create file name and pass it to nodeJS
     var fileName = "yourFileName";
     var e = document.createElement('a');
     e.href = window.location.origin + "/api/v1/home/downloadList/" + Id + "/" + fileName;
     e.target = '_blank';
     document.body.appendChild(e);
     e.click();
     document.body.removeChild(e);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is related to my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56002172/3639777), edited for csv and your code.

Apparently this is a [Safari 12 bug](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=197441) that *sometimes* happens. It's not fixed by `target = "_self"`, which pertains to a [different regression bug](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=190351).

Until the bug is fixed, the ugly workaround is:

1. Send the blob to the server which saves the file remotely.
2. Download the remote file.

**Javascript Code**

```
   async createDownloadElementAndClick(csvFile, fileName) {
            let options = {
                method:"POST",
                body:csvFile
            };

            await fetch(`https://example.com/upload.php`, options);

            window.open(`https://example.com/download.php?${fileName}`, "_self");
    }
```

So from your original code, change to:

```
 var convertedCsv = "name,Designation,City,State,email,mobileNumber,roleType,signUpDate+\n" +
                    "A,B,C,D,F,G,I,J \n" +
                    "A1,B1,C1,D1,F1,G1,I1,J1";
 var data = new Blob([convertedCsv], {type: 'text/csv'});
 var csvFile = window.URL.createObjectURL(data);
 //just add this to replace window.open()
 createDownloadElementAndClick(csvFile, "myFile.csv")
```

**PHP Code**

In upload.php:

```
<?php    
// add any authentication code as necessary here


    // gets entire POST body
    $data = file_get_contents('php://input');

    $filename = "temp/download.csv";
    // write the data out to the file
    $fp = fopen($filename, 'wb');

    fwrite($fp, $data);
    fclose($fp);
?>
```

In download.php:

```
<?php
    ob_start();
    $file = $_SERVER["QUERY_STRING"];

    // This is the line that tells Safari to download the file instead of opening it
    header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=$file");
    header("Content-type: text/csv", false);
    readfile("temp/download.csv");

    ob_flush();
    // This deletes the file so there is little chance of contaminating the next call
    unlink("temp/download.csv");
?>
```